# Error 13 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cudnn.h': No such file or directory ...\caffe\util\cudnn.hpp 5 1 convert_imageset

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2013, deep-learning, caffe, cudnn

When I compile caffe for windows (64bit, release, vs 2013, nvidia 750, opencv 3.1,`cuDNN` version 5.1), I got the following error

> "Error    13  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cudnn.h': No such
>   file or directory ...\caffe\util\cudnn.hpp    5   1   convert_imageset".

I set everything like what mentioned in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrzAF2sxHHM).

I search for this error in github issues link [this](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/1325)  and [this](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/3969)

if I use version 4 of `cuDNN` and `OpenCV 2.4`I got:

> ========== Rebuild All: 15 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

However, I got error:

> Error 1 error MSB3073: The command
>   ""...\caffe-master\windows\scripts\BinplaceCudaDependencies‌​.cmd"
>   "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\bin"
>   "...\cuda" false true "...\caffe-master\windows..\Build\x64\Release\"
>   :VCEnd" exited with code 1. C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.ta‌​rgets
>   132 5 libcaffe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the cuDNN archive to a directory of your choice, referred to below as *installpath*. Then follow the platform-specific instructions as follows:

- Add *installpath* to the PATH environment variable.
- In your Visual Studio project properties, add *installpath* to the Include Directories and Library Directories lists and add cudnn.lib to Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies.